# How to open a subprocess (within a python script) in new terminal and kill it after 15 seconds (Platform: Ubuntu)

Tags: python, bash, subprocess, timeout, terminate

I am trying to start a subprocess in a new window from a python script file - timeout for 15 seconds then terminate that process without closing the main terminal window.

this is what I have so far...

```
cmd=subprocess.Popen('file_name.sh')
subprocess.Popen('gnome terminal -c cmd')
time.sleep(15)
Popen.terminate(cmd)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
import subprocess
import time

proc = subprocess.Popen(('gnome-terminal', '--', 'file_name.sh')) 
time.sleep(15)
subprocess.Popen(('pkill', '-f', 'file_name.sh'))
```

Comment: That works! Thank you so much. One other question - is there a way to send keys to close that terminal window? - Ctrl+Shift+Q

Comment: In my test, gnome-terminal disappeared when file_name.sh finished/killed.

Comment: Ok - maybe it's some setting in Terminal then - I get a yellow bar at the top that says "The child process was stopped with signal 15" then gives me the option to Relaunch - I have to press ctrl+shift+Q to close the window manually

Comment: Preferences->Unnamed->Command->Exit Window

Comment: Thank you so much sir - I've been banging my head against a wall trying to learn python and switching over from windows to linux has been challenging... one day at a time.. you are a life saver. :)